# $M$ be a complete $R$-module and $N$ be a closed submodule of $M.$ Then $M/N$ is complete.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, topological-groups

Let $M$ be a complete $R$-module with respect to the filteration $\{M_n\}.$ Also let $N$ be a closed submodule of $M.$ Then how can I show that $M/N$ is complete with respect to the induced filteration, i.e., $\{(M/N)_n=(N+M_n)/N\}.$

We should show that $M/N$ is Hausdorff and every Cauchy sequence in $M/N$ converges. Since $N= \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}(N+M_n)$ clearly $M/N$ is Hausdorff. But How can I show that every Cauchy sequence in $M/N$ is convergent ? I need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A Cauchy sequence in $M/N$ has the form $\{x_n+N\}$, where the $x_n\in M$ satisfy  relations $x_{n+1}-x_n\in N+M_{s(n)}$ with $s(n)\to \infty$. Though $\{x_n\}$ might not be a Cauchy sequence in $M$ we can a define a Cauchy sequence $\{y_n\}$ in $M$ such that $x_n\equiv y_n\mod N$. The procedure is as follows. We set $y_1=x_1$. Assume that we have defined $y_n$ so that $y_n\equiv x_n\mod N$. Note that $x_{n+1}-x_n-u\in M_{s(n)}$ for some $u\in N$. We thus define $y_{n+1}=x_{n+1}-(x_n-y_n)-u$. By construction we have $y_{n+1}\equiv x_{n+1}\mod N$ and $y_{n+1}-y_n=x_{n+1}-x_n-u\in M_{s(n)}$. It follows that $\{y_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $M$ and has therefore a limit, say $y\in M$. It is now easy to see that $y+N$ is the limit of $\{x_n+N\}=\{y_n+N\}$.

Comment: How $y_n$ is a Cauchy ? And also how a Cauchy sequence will imply the first line i.e., $x_{n+1} - x_n \in N + M_{s(n)}$ for large... ? What is true is that after certain stage they are sufficiently close right !

Comment: Hi! I am using: Let $M$ be an $R$-module with a filtration $\{M_n\}$. Let $\{x_n\}$ be any sequence in $M$. For each $n$, we define $s(n)$ as the largest positive integer such that $x_n-x_{n+1}\in M_{s(n)}$. If there are none, we set $s(n)=0$ and if this holds for all $n$ then we could define $s(n)=n$. Then $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence if and only if $s(n)\to\infty$.